# Converting datenum field as a date field in jasper domain

Tags: jasperserver

I'm trying to create a calculated field in a jasper domain which is a value of field is Datenum. I need to convert that datenum into a date format (1/1/16 or like this) while creating the calculated field.
I have tried by only changing the datatype from number to date. but it only gives something like this(1/1/70). I have attached screenshots below. 
Are there any way to use this field as date field.
[image: This image looks when I have changed only the datatype]

[image: This is the calculated field which I have created in the Domain]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Conversion**

First, you are not using any function to tell Jasper that you need a date. You have only set the data type to date. Since Java date began counting at 01.01.1970 this is the date you get.

The calculated field doesn't know how to interpret your data in the format `20160101`. It is possible to use a [DomEL function](http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/jasperreports-server-user-guide/domel-syntax) called `date` in the expression which interprets a date in ANSI format:

```
date('2016-01-01')
```

Nonetheless the format of the field `SUBMITDATENUM` is different. The date function will not be able to interpret this. Unfortunately I am not aware if it is possible to provide a format in which the data is interpreted.

**Datebase options**

If you can change the format of the table structure, simply add another field or change the data format of the field (if feasible). Otherwise, you could add a database view which converts the field into a "real" date field.

This is the solution I would go for.

**More options**

There might be a possibility in version 6 with `Groovy` since [it can be used inline](http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jasperreports-server-user-guide/v62/sql-functions):

```
<field id="e.groovyEval" dataSetExpression="groovy('(5.0/6).toString()')" type="java.lang.String" />
```

So with the correct `Groovy` function (which I haven't used yet - I don't know if variables can be inserted) this could help:

```
<field id="e.groovyDate" dataSetExpression="groovy('Date.parse(\'yyyyMMdd\', ASASMARTLAYER_PHWORDERSPAN.SUBMITDATENUM)')" type="java.lang.Date" />
```

Comment: Thank you for the complete answer you  have given..... I think query level changes are most suitable in these kind of situations. Am I correct..???

Comment: I'd always go for the correct datatype in the database first to get everything in the format I need.